# Color d3 area based on computed value

Tags: d3.js, graph, nested, data-visualization, fill

I've created a line graph with `d3.nest()` objects, but I need the fill color for each segment to be based on another variable. I thought I could just do it based on the `gradient` from the data file, but it actually needs to be computed over the distance of the segment. Right now, everything is coming back as one color when it should be

```
if gradient < -10
     color = red
if gradient < -5
     color = green
if gradient < 0
     color = white
if gradient < 5
     color = yellow
if gradient < 10
     color = black
else
     color = blue
```

Here's a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyzVKRWpWqozCrGkkfkn?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

text.shadow {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid path {
          stroke-width: 0;
}

.area {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 35, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([-10,-5,0,5,10])
    .range(['red','green','white','yellow','black','blue']);

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.distance); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.elevation); });

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.distance); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.elevation); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// function for the x grid lines
function make_x_axis() {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5)
}

// function for the y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(5)
}

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.distance = +d.distance;
        d.elevation = +d.elevation;
        d.gradient = +d.gradient;
    });

    var dataGroup = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {
            return d.grade;
        })
        .entries(data);

    dataGroup.forEach(function(group, i) {
      if(i < dataGroup.length - 1) {
        group.values.push(dataGroup[i+1].values[0])
      }
    })

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.distance; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.elevation; })]);

    dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i){
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(d.values)
            .attr("class", "area")
            .attr("d", area);
        });

    svg.selectAll(".area")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.gradient); });

    // Draw the x Grid lines
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(make_x_axis()
            .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Draw the y Grid lines
    svg.append("g")            
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
        )

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Add the text label for the X axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                             (height+margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Distance");

    // Add the text label for the Y axis
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", margin.top - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("");

    // Add the title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))     
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", "16px")
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")
        .text("Elevation Graph");

});

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this call:

```
svg.selectAll(".area")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.gradient); });
```

Here, "d" is an array of objects of length one or two depending on the index. I don't know which object's gradient you wish to use, but my naive solution without understanding your data would be to use d[0]. Here's the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BhTGwJbaVTI6q1Y0tBRZ?p=preview).

Comment: That's really close. What I really need is to take the mean of the gradients in the array.